# BigQuery load local file doesn't work, something wrong with location

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Trying to replicate this example:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-from-file

- `writer.job` is null for "us" location
- `404` at `bigQuery.writer(job, writeChannelConfiguration)` for any other location

What is working

- connection works
- table is created via java API, Data location is set to **us** (I have no idea why). Is it possible to control it? I would prefer `"europe-west2"`

Here is my scala code:

```scala
 val table = createBigQueryTable(metadata, datasetName, tableName)
    log.info(s"table: $table")
    val tableId = table.getTableId
    log.info(s"tableId: $tableId")
// GenericData{classInfo=[datasetId, projectId, tableId], 
// {datasetId=my_dataset, projectId=my_project_id tableId=my_new_table}} 
    val writeChannelConfiguration: WriteChannelConfiguration = WriteChannelConfiguration
      .newBuilder(tableId)
      .setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.parquet())
      .build
    // tried these locations: "us", "europe-west2", "US"
    val job = JobId.newBuilder().setLocation(location).build()
    // throws 404 for all except location = "us"
    // but writer.getJob is null for "us"
    val writer: TableDataWriteChannel = bigQuery.writer(job, writeChannelConfiguration)
    val stream: OutputStream = Channels.newOutputStream(writer)
    Files.copy(parquetGzipFile.toPath, stream)

    // Get load job
    val jobInProgress = writer.getJob
    // returns null for location = "us"
   
    log.info(s"jobInProgress: $jobInProgress")

    val completedJob = jobInProgress.waitFor()
    log.info(s"completedJob: $completedJob")
    val stats = completedJob.getStatistics
    log.info(s"stats: $stats")
    stats
```

how is it supposed to work?

BTW, will this API load 100 mb file?

UPD:

- answer explains what's going on wrong with location
- answer gives a clue about job status polling

Referenced example doesn't work for some reason. Snippet with job helps.

```scala
// Set location, project explicitly for JobId
val jobId: JobId = JobId.newBuilder()
      .setLocation(location)
      .setProject(table.getTableId.getProject)
      // generates UUID under the hood. 
      .setRandomJob()
      .build()
    log.info(s"job: $jobId")
    val writer: TableDataWriteChannel = bigQuery.writer(jobId, writeChannelConfiguration)
    val stream: OutputStream = Channels.newOutputStream(writer)
    Files.copy(parquetGzipFile.toPath, stream)
    writer.close() // close it

    // Get load job by jobId
    val jobInProgress = bigQuery.getJob(jobId)
    log.info(s"jobInProgress: $jobInProgress")
    val completedJob = jobInProgress.waitFor()
    log.info(s"completedJob: $completedJob")
    val stats = completedJob.getStatistics.asInstanceOf[JobStatistics]
    log.info(s"stats: $stats")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question for the 404 error and the `writer.job` "null" value.

- You encounter the 404 error because there is a location mismatch. Your dataset is located in US (default value if location is not specified) and you are trying to run a job in a different location. I suggest that if you'd like to run a job in "europe-west2", dataset should be located in "europe-west2" upon creation. See [specifying locations document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#specifying_your_location) for more details.
- See [creating a dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-create-dataset) on how to create a dataset and set its location.
- You get "null" value for `writer.job` becuase the job object does not have a field for `location`. Location is used as an input to [get job information](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#view_information_about_jobs). See REST reference for [Job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job). If you want to get the `location` you can get it from the [dataset information](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-metadata#getting_dataset_information). See REST reference for [Dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets#Dataset).

The API should be able to load a 100MB file since the maximum allowable size for uncompressed CSV is 5TB. See [CSV loading limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs).